# K-means clustering on data set with mixed data using Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am experimenting with machine learning algorithms and have a pretty large data set containing both numerical and categorical data. I followed this post here: http://www.ritchieng.com/machinelearning-one-hot-encoding/ to encode categorical features to numerical:

I want to try K-means clustering of the whole data set for instance. I am not sure how to use this encoded data array I have now as a part of the original data frame in order to run machine learning algorithms. I would really appreciate an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you have one-hot-encoded your data. In order to use K-means clustering then, it is important to rescale your data because you might have some numerical features which will dominate your clustering. You may try several rescalers from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) (the most famous are MinMaxScaler and StandardScaler).

After that you can refer [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) to see how to use KMeans with sklearn. In general the steps are the following:

You import KMeans:

`from sklearn.cluster import KMeans`

You instantiate an KMeans object, specifying at least the number of clusters, here I put arbitrarily 8:

`kmeans =  KMeans(n_clusters = 8)`

Then you fit the object with the data (here my data is named X):

`kmeans.fit(X)`

After that you can see the cluster assigned to each row using `.labels_`:

`kmeans.labels_`

You may also predict the cluster for a new and unseen data (named lets say new_X) using `.predict`:

`kmeans.predict(new_X)`

Comment: Thanks @elkoul for pointing out rescaling. What I am most wondering is how to use this one-hot encoded data with the normal data frame i.e how to append this big array consisting of 0's and 1's to the data frame that contains floating point numbers.

Comment: One easy way to do one hot encoding is to use `pandas.get_dummies`. You may have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Comment: Thank you @elkoul